# Populate Gravity Form field with Product Name

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms, auto-populate

I have a customer query form, so when the customer clicks on the inquire button from the product page, i need the product name field to be auto-populated with the product name the customer clicked from. I am new to this hence not having many ideas! any help would be appreciated.

Attaching SS for reference

[Inquiry-Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6yn.png)
[Product-Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhG6H.png)

Comment: Is the product name in the URL?  Does that button contain a pop-up to the form or does it go to an alternate page all together

Comment: yes, the product name is in the URL and the form opens on another page altogether.